# Multi-column Primary Key vs Auto-Increment

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I made two columns to be Primary.

One Column is an `INT`, the other is an `nvarchar(200)`.

Now something like this is actually allowed:

```
Int  Varchar
1    FIRSTENTRY
1    SECONDENTRY
2    FIRSTENTRY
2    SECONDENTRY
```

I made the INT Column an Identity which increments by 1.

The Problem is:
When I INSERT new Columns it counts always up. Lets say I INSERTED the columns like this:

```
FIRSTENTRY
SECONDENTRY
FIRSTENTRY
SECONDENTRY
```

The Table looks then like this:

```
1 - FIRSTENTRY
2 - SECONDENTRY
3 - FIRSTENTRY
4 - SECONDENTRY
```

I want it to be like this:

```
1 - FIRSTENTRY
1 - SECONDENTRY
2 - FIRSTENTRY
2 - SECONDENTRY
```

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: You can't use identity if this is what you want. I would suggest you keep the identity and use ROW_NUMBER to determine the group sequence.

Comment: Why not leave the ID as an auto inc column  and make a groupID column as a non clustered with the text included or will you always be querying by the GroupID and text?

Answer (score 1):

You can't: `IDENTITY` always increments, being part of a composite key plays no role.

Or in other words, there is no such thing as '*do the auto-increment only if it is needed to avoid a duplicate composite key*'.

You will need to generate the recurring/repeating values yourself using custom written logic.

**Update:**
You might also want to consider separating the two: an `EntryGroup` table that has a IDENTITY Primary Key, and an `Entry` table that has a column `EntryGroupID` that is a Foreign Key to the `EntryGroup` table. Sooner or later you may find that the EntityGroups are actually relevant entities in your system, and then you'll be glad if you separated them at such an early stage.

Comment: Turn identity insert on and never let it auto generate? But that <-- should be taken as a bad joke